# Выбор backend-сервер технологий для mobile social app

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, backend

Прошу совета вот по какому вопросу.
Сейчас находится в зачаточном состоянии мобильный проект. Сам я Джавист с крайне небольшим опытом работы. Пока стартап будет писаться самим на коленках, а если выстрелит, то будет нанята команда программистов-бодибилдеров.

Вопрос. **Какую схему и технологию использовать для backend мобильного приложения? Мне в голову приходит только Java + Spring + REST + MongoBD + JSON.** Будет ли на перспективу такая схема держать высокую нагрузку множественных коннектов и запросов. Сейчас это будет 5 запросов в час, а на перспективу может быть и 1000 запросов в секунду.

***Требования.***

- backend желательно на java, т.к. я сам буду писать поначалу.
- Специфика проекта - "инстаграм для трёх калек". Поэтому не реляционная MongoDB
- Клиенты будут цепляться по android (сам буду писать) и iOS на аутсерсе заказывать.
- **Насколько оправдана схема Java + Spring + REST + MongoBD + JSON вообще?** Как работают социальные мессенджеры и сети в микромасштабе? По JSON over HTTP?

---

Так никто ничего и не может сказать. 
Я тут прошерстил инфу. 
Что лучше держит нагрузки на backend при множественных подключениях?

Spring REST или websocket ?

Comment: `программистов-бодибилдеров` - это чем надо заниматься дабы стать таким?

Comment: Да это сарказм.

Answer (score 2):

Хочешь Rest (т.е. одноразовые запросы):

1. Node js -  Ассинхронность, хорошее масштабирование, не требует типизированного кода (хотя типизация на некотором лвл'е присутствует)
   При 10к соединений -  ответ в 170+ мс
2. php, а конкретнее посоветовал бы Symfony 4+ и FOS Rest к нему в придачу
   Rest писать изумительно удобно, начиная с 4 версии симфонии 80% кода можно написать при помощи комментариев, много функций для генерации интерфейсов  к таблицам БД (моделей), генерации самих таблиц и прочего

Хочешь реалтайм соединения, тогда websoket - выбирай в порядке возрастания из node.js, Java, C (любой из семейства)

А теперь конкретно по вашей задаче:
Сейчас мессенджеры пишутся несколькими способами

1. Pooling - асинхронный  запросы на Rest, по приходу ответа которого, посылается новый. Таким образом идёт вечный опрос новых сообщений и инфы от друзей и подписчиков и т.п.
2. Замена http запросов (пулинга) на коннект (websoket) - смысл тот же, только вместо того чтобы вечно опрашивать сервер на наличие новой инфы (а серверу собственно каждый раз подготавливать ответ и отвечать), создаётся единоразовый коннект и сервер сам отправляет новые данные, если таковы есть.
   Нагрузки вычислений на сервере падают, но вот нагрузка памяти увеличивается, т.к. соединение для каждого клиента надо держать открытым.

Это что касается мессенджера, отдельно должен быть обычный Rest, для статических запросов не требующих поддержки соединения (логин, регистрация, получение инфы, списка друзей, групп и прочих вещей)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. В данный момент Node.js не рассматривается, т.к. java знаю, а в js еще плаваю сильно и куча шишек на своём проекте не хочется набивать. Как я понимаю может быть схема Spring + REST по websocket   ???

Comment: @ЮрийГагарин, можно Spring для Rest и поверх его HTTP сервера на другом порту открыть web socket соединение.
Но присоединятся к нему нужно не во всех частях клиента, а только в нужных случаях: для обмена сообщениями.
А для информирования о новых сообщениях со стороны сервера на любой странице, можно использовать теже Push уведомления

Comment: Добавил бы, что для удобной работы с node.js можно использовать express